# How to fetch unique characters in string

Tags: java, string

Need a function which takes in a String and outputs array of unique characters in that String.
input: "abccddeee"
output: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

Comment: This is probably a one-liner using lambdas. Which is probably not what your instructor wants for this homework.

Comment: @jdv not exactly one-liner, because converting `IntStream` produced by `CharSequence#chars()` requires intermediate mapping...

Comment: Couldnt find the apt solution.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou, oh, right. In my mind we had a char array we were consuming. Still, a good candidate for a lambda.

Comment: I am very disappointed in everyone who just offered a solution to this homework. You all have my full disapproval, and you know what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `Set<Character>` to get rid of duplicates and if you need to have some order use a `LinkedHashSet<Character>` (insert order) or a `TreeSet<Character>` (arbitrary order).

Example:

```
String string = "aabbeeddffcc";

Set<Character> chars = new TreeSet<>();
for( char c : string.toCharArray() ) {
  chars.add(c);
}

System.out.println( chars );
```

Output: `[a, b, c, d, e, f]`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe stream?

```
List<Character> disinctChars 
     = input.chars()                        // get chars as ints
            .distinct()                     // remove duplicates
            .sorted()                       // sort
            .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)        // convert int to Character
            .collect(Collectors.toList());  // collect in a List
```

`distinct()` and `sorted()` can be omited if you collect into a `SortedSet`:

```
Set<Character> distinctChars 
     = input.chars()
            .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```

Comment: PlusOne because, you know, streams. Why should C# get all the fun?

Comment: @jdv I also tried your suggestion about streaming array produced by `input.toCharArray()`. Unfortunately `Stream.of(input.toCharArray())` returned `Stream<char[]>`--autoboxing doesn't happen here :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Set?

```
String s = "abccddeee";
Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();
 for (Character c : s.toCharArray()) {
             set.add(c);
  }
 System.out.println(set);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a Set since that collection doesnt accept duplicates..

## Example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String txt = "abccddeee";
    Set<Character> uniqueStr = new HashSet<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < txt.length(); i++) {
        uniqueStr.add(txt.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println(uniqueStr);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:

```
  public static void fancyStringFunction(String input) {
    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
      System.out.println(c);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This will print each character as often as it occurs in the string - duplicates are not filtered.